# How do I draw samples from this distribution?

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions

Let S be the the standard K-1 simplex. Consider the following probability distribution:

$$\begin{align}
f(p,\alpha,\beta) &= \prod_{k=1}^K p_k^{\alpha_k-1}(1-p_k)^{\beta_k-1}\\
Z(\alpha,\beta) &= \int_{S} f(p,\alpha,\beta) dp_1dp_2..dp_K\\
\Pr(P=p; \alpha,\beta) &= \frac{f(p,\alpha,\beta) }{Z(\alpha,\beta)}
\end{align}$$

How do I draw a sample from this distribution?

Does Z have a closed form?

Comment: can you give some info on where this comes from? it looks like a multivariate beta distribution, but not quite, so I'm puzzled how it arises.

Comment: You can always use a Metropolis algorithm with proposal moves given by a reflecting random walk on the probability simplex.

Comment: Gibbs sampling might be a reasonable approach here.